# Spring MVC get value of onclick input star rating

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, controller

I'm coding a java spring mvc web application, and on client side I'm using bootstrap and a star rating plugin to show appreciation for a list of song I'm displaying to the user.

What I'm doing is passing the playlist I generated in the session, and in the jsp iterating this list to create a table that fits correctly. On the side of the song name\title I want to display a star rating system; I did it but it's set as a input number. What I want to do is, on a star click, redirecting to another page, retrieving the rate in the controller, make some logic and then return the playlist page without that song.

I'm having some difficulties, because on the controller, to understand which song has been rated, I obviously have to put the id of the song as a input parameter, so the name of the input is something like "input2838", but on the controller side when I have to request the parameters with `RequestParameter` value, I need to specify exactly the name of the parameter I want, so I think it's not the right thing to do.

I ask you for suggestions on how to do this kind of stuff, and, most of all, how to redirect to another page, passing the value of the parameter, when I click that input...

I show you the jsp snippet of code where I display the table of songs.

```
<script>$("#input-id").rating();</script> <-- initialize the stars script

<c:choose>    <-- when the playlist is not empty show it
  <c:when test="${not empty playlist}">
   <div class="container col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" >
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Cover</th>
                <th>Artista</th>
                <th>Titolo</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

<c:forEach items="${playlist}" var="canzone" varStatus="count">
<tr style="font-weight: normal">
  <td style="font-weight: normal">${count.index +1}</td>
  <td style="font-weight: normal"><img src="${canzone.albumImageUrl}" /></td>
  <td style="font-weight: normal">${canzone.artistName}</td>
  <td class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight: normal">${canzone.title}</td>
<td class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight: normal"><div><input id="input-id" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-rtl="false"></div></td>
       <tr>
    </c:forEach>
            </tbody>

    </table>
    </div>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
```

Now I post you for sake of completeness the star rating js as a pastebin link:

[Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/bLGsUTnv)

Do not hesitate to ask other infos.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if you get all the songs id which is specified in table as `id="sondId"` or `name="sondId"`, and by using `request.getParameter("songId")`, it wont pick the correct value coz of all the rows will be containing same id and name.

So what you need to do is inside the `<c:forEach>` enter a , like below

```
<c:forEach items="${playlist}" var="canzone" varStatus="count">
    <form action="yourActionPath" method="post">
        <tr style="font-weight: normal">
            <input type="hidden" id="songId" name="songId" value="${canzone.id}"/>
            <td style="font-weight: normal">${count.index +1}</td>
            <td style="font-weight: normal"><img src="${canzone.albumImageUrl}" /></td>
            <td style="font-weight: normal">${canzone.artistName}</td>
            <td class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight: normal">${canzone.title}</td>
            <td class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight: normal"><div><input id="input-id" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-rtl="false"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

You have to decide on how to submit the form after you specified the stars, like onchange() or something else. This is not very good choice, but just what I know..

Comment: Then put the form outside the <tr> tag, updated my answer, take a look

Comment: it somehow tells me it can't see the </form> closing tag...
http://pastebin.com/VF42RDbA

Comment: In your code which you posted in question, you didn't closed the <tr> tag. You ended the <tr> as <tr> instead of </tr> . Also do not forget the put the </form> close tag after </tr> .. I think you didnt closed a tag propely..

Comment: I closed the tr on the line 14!

Comment: where is </c:forEach>, I can't find the closing tag for for Each in pastebin code